# How to enable/disable push notification from the app iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've an iOS app and what i need to enable/disable the push notification from the setting page from my app; i use the following code to enable the push notification

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |  UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

and this code to disable push notification

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
```

but its not working with iOS 8 i receive the following message on debug

```
enabledRemoteNotificationTypes is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later
```

Can any one suggest me a solution to turn on/off the status of app in notification center from the app ?

Comment: any help please; need anybody give me the guide

Answer (score 0):

Register:

```
UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeSound);

UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Unregister:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using below way & it worked..

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
  //Right, that is the point
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
#else
    //register to receive notifications
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
#endif
```

Add below method for iOS 8.0

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    //handle the actions
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score -2):

The `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` method is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:). Apple lists the new method that you should use (`registerForRemoteNotifications`).

Hard to tell if your question is about the warning you get, or about it functioning as you expect it to.

Comment: my question is about the correct way to enable/disable push notification from the setting view on my app